# python unable to parse table name correctly in sql query

Tags: python, python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am newbie to snowflake. I am trying to fetch ddl s of all tables in my db using python script.

```
import snowflake.connector
import sys


# Gets the version
cnx = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='username',
    password='password',
    account='account',
    database='db',
    schema='schema',
    warehouse='warehouse',
    role='role'
    )
cnx.cursor().execute("USE warehouse warehouseName") 
cnx.cursor().execute("USE database dbName")
cnx = cnx.cursor()

dbSchema='schema name'

sql_select_objects = "select TABLE_NAME,TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_TYPE from  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='" + dbSchema + "';"

print(sql_select_objects)

try:
    cnx.execute(sql_select_objects)
    print('Query ID=' + cnx.sfqid)

    rows = cnx.fetchall()
    print("rows count:", len(rows))
    for row in rows:
        #print(row[0])
        file = open(row[0] + ".sql","w")
        rw='"' + row[0] + '"'
        print(rw)
        sql_ddl_object = "SELECT GET_DDL('TABLE', '" + row[0] + "')"
        print(sql_ddl_object)
        cnx.execute(sql_ddl_object)
        print('SQL2 sfqid=' + cnx.sfqid)
        row_ddl_table = cnx.fetchall()
        #print(row_ddl_table[0][0])
        file.write(str(row_ddl_table[0][0]))
        file.write("\n")
    
finally:
    cnx.close()
```

When I execute above script i get error:

> snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 002003 (02000): SQL compilation error:
>
> Table 'SNOWFLAKE_TEST' does not exist or not authorized.

in line "SELECT GET_DDL('TABLE', '" + row[0] + "')", i believe python is not **parsing  value of row[0]** correctly. Can you please suggest me where the error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use both schema and table name as you may have the table SNOWFLAKE_TEST in a different schema:

```
"SELECT GET_DDL('TABLE', '" + row[1] + "." + row[0] + "')"
```

I would also surround the table name and schema names in double quotes because maybe your schema or table is created with a case-sensitive name:

```
"SELECT GET_DDL('TABLE', '\"" + row[1] + "\".\"" + row[0] + "\"')"
```

Comment: thanks for quick suggestion. i have now changed table name to fully qualified name as "dbName"."schemaName"."tableName". script has worked

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue is not with the table name but the role that you are using in the code. The role most likely does not have access to the DB and it's table hence the error message is seen.

Comment: The TABLES view only displays objects for which the current role for the session has been granted access privileges. FYI

Comment: there is no issue with role. i m giving role in connection itself so it should not cause issue